# Rails double-entry method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**1-account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :transaction
end

class Supplier < Account
end

class Expense < Account
end
```

**2-transaction.rb**

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :accounts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts
end
```

**3-migration schema**

```
create_table "accounts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "debit"
    t.decimal  "credit"
    t.decimal  "balance"
    t.string   "type"
    t.integer  "transaction_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "transactions", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "amount"
    t.date     "date"
    t.string   "document"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

*Question1*:
What's the best method to reach supplier and expense in the view (see the picture below)?

*Question2*:
How can I implement a method that automatically record the transaction amount in `expense_debit` and `supplier_credit`, and vice versa? ([View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1QQB.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest an alternative setup. For one thing, your transaction does not record which is the "from" account and which is the "to" account. That's kind of important to know for later.

I recognise that there may be multiple accounts from and to... but debit vs credit should be recorded on a per-transaction basis, not in just one big lump on the Account, otherwise it'll be difficult later to, say, list the change in an account's value between date A and date B (important for tax-returns or quarterly sales reports or whatever).

i don't know about naming, but perhaps a transaction has_many account-transfers and a transfer is "transaction_id, account_id, amount, direction" (where direction is debit/credit).

Comment: thanks for your answer Taryn East.I'm going to try your solution.Matter fact I never thought of creating a model as a link between transactions and accounts.I hope the account-transfers model will do the trick.I promess to give you a feedback very soon.